# In text citation and reference list not working with natbib package in latex

Tags: latex

I am very new to latex.
I would like to cite the sentence below using the natbib package. However, using the code below shows question marks in the in-text citation and my reference list does not appear. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

Blablabla blabla blabla “Blablabla blablabla blablabla” \citep[p.~339]{author2015sociology}.

\end{document}
```

Below is the citation in the bibliography.bib file:

```
@article{author2015sociology,
  title={Article Title},
  author={Author 1, Author_2, Author_3 and Author_4},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={19},
  number={2},
  pages={174--204},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Publisher: City, CA}
}
```

Comment: The natbib package is for usage with bibtex, not with biblatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- the `natbib` package is for use with bibtex, not biblatex. If you want to use commands like `\citep`, you can pass the `natbib=true` option to biblatex
- `\printbibliography` is missing
- `\bibliography{...}` is bibtex syntax. Use `\addbibresource` instead if you use biblatex
- the syntax for the authors is wrong. Use `and` in between author and not `,`
- compile with `pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, `pdflatex`

---

```
\documentclass[jou]{apa7}
%\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber,natbib=true]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{author2015sociology,
  title={Article Title},
  author={James Author and Clark Author and Richard Author and Tom Author},
  journal={Journal},
  volume={19},
  number={2},
  pages={174--204},
  year={2015},
  publisher={Publisher: City, CA}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Blablabla blabla blabla "Blablabla blablabla blablabla" \citep[p.~339]{author2015sociology}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```